# Page factory performance

Tags: selenium2, java, selenium-webdriver

Does page factory affect on performance for test execution when we have a lot of   elements  with `@FindBy`? We use Java as a programming language.

Comment: AFAIR, Java implementation of `PageFactory` decorates `WebElement`s with dynamic proxy. So more information about impact of such proxies on performance can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856242/performance-cost-of-java-dynamic-proxy

Comment: you may want to clarify which implementation/programming language you meant.

Comment: @dzieciou Thank you for your answer, I added programming language.

Comment: @dzieciou why didn't you post the answer? It is definitely worth upvoating.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Posted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Java implementation of `PageFactory` decorates `WebElement`s with a [dynamic proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html). So more information about impact of such proxies on performance can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856242/performance-cost-of-java-dynamic-proxy), among questions related to dynamic proxy.